# Moshi cannot find my custom adapter written in Kotlin for a parameterized type

Tags: java, json, kotlin, moshi

I have a custom JSON adapter for Moshi for a list of byte strings like the following.

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class HexString

object ByteStringListAdapter {
  @ToJson fun toJson(@HexString byteStrings: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards ByteString>): List<String> {
    return byteStrings.map { it.hex() }
  }

  @FromJson @HexString fun fromJson(json: List<String>): List<@JvmSuppressWildcards ByteString> {
    return json.map { ByteString.decodeHex(it) }
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
      .add(ByteStringListAdapter)
      .build()
  val byteStringListAdapter = moshi.adapter<List<ByteString>>(
      Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, ByteString::class.java), HexString::class.java)
}
```

Even though I have registered it properly in `main` here, running this program will fail with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No @ToJson adapter for java.util.List<okio.ByteString> annotated [@HexString()]`.

Why is Moshi not finding my registered adapter for `@HexString List<ByteString>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toJson` function needs [`@JvmSuppressWildcards`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-suppress-wildcards/index.html) on the parameter.

```
@ToJson fun toJson(@HexString byteStrings: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards ByteString>): List<String> {
  return byteStrings.map { it.hex() }
}
```

Without it, Moshi sees `List<? extends ByteString>` and cannot match the types to find the adapter.